# Dose the 'v-model' do something more in Vue2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
<template>
  <div>
    value: {{ obj.c }}
    <my-input v-model="obj.c"/>
    <my-input :value="obj.c" @change="(val) => (obj.c = val)"/>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data(){
    return {
      obj: {}
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

`my-input` is a customer component. `v-model` will update the View, but the other will not.
These two methods are inequivalence ?
What else did the 'v-model' do ?

Answer (score 0):

`v-model` is a two-way data binding attribute for form inputs and `:value` is a one-way data binding attribute which binds a JavaScript value into the template and to update the value we can use `v-on:input` in addition to `:value`.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    vModelMessage: 'Hello Vue.js!',
    valueMessage: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="vModelMessage"/>
  {{ vModelMessage }}
  <br><br>
  <input type="text" :value="valueMessage" v-on:input="valueMessage = $event.target.value"/>
  {{ valueMessage }}
</div>
```